# facebook php re-authentication : app to server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

our app is 2 tier, the phone apps (ios + droid) and our php api.

a use can login via our own username/password system or login via facebook.

when i use logs in via facebook it uses native fb sdk. this works great.

but to access our api, they need to register for an oauth token. this usually happens via login. but since login is being faciliated via fb on the app, the api has no idea about this authentication proccess.

i need a way to pass some identifier from facebook to the api, and let the api validate the identifier then create a token for the app to use to communicate with our api.

my first guess was to use facebook's reauthentication mechanism:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/

but all these examples are using the javascript sdk. i cannot find any documentation for this in the context of their php sdk.

is this possible? or am i going in the wrong direction here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, i think i have found a solution.

the mobile app logs in and is given a "code" from facebook. the app passes the code to my api and the api calls: the facebook sdk method: `getAccessTokenFromCode` (i had to change it from protected to public). this returns an error if the user is not logged in, or a token and a expiration date/time if they are logged in. if i get a token response, i add a token in my database and let my api work as normal. hope this helps someone...

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx'
));
$token = $fb->getAccessTokenFromCode(
    $args['fb_code'],
    'http://mydomain.com/'
);
```